# BatchNormalization blows up keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I try to train a model on keras with tensorflow as backend with the following code:

```
CHANNEL_AXIS = 3

img_width, img_height = 513, 128
nb_classes = 10
batch_size = 64

input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
inputs = layers.Input(input_shape)

tempModel = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=(4, 513), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(inputs)

shortcut = tempModel

tempModel = layers.BatchNormalization(axis = CHANNEL_AXIS)(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Activation('relu')(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=(4, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=None)(tempModel)

tempModel = layers.BatchNormalization(axis = CHANNEL_AXIS)(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Activation('relu')(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=(4, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', activation=None)(tempModel)

tempModel = layers.add([shortcut, tempModel])

max_p_layer = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(data_format='channels_last')(tempModel)
avg_p_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last')(tempModel)

tempModel = layers.concatenate([max_p_layer, avg_p_layer])
tempModel = layers.Dense(300, activation='relu')(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Dropout(0.2)(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Dense(150, activation='relu')(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Dropout(0.2)(tempModel)
tempModel = layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(tempModel)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=tempModel)
```

Now when I try to train the model, the training is terribly slow, especially compared to other architectures with even more parameters. Furthermore, the model requires much more memory (in total over 30 Gigabytes without weights) and I think this is because of the BatchNormalization Layers (at least the model used a few gigabytes less, when I removed them for testing purposes). Did I implement the network wrongly or are the BatchNormalization Layers just terribly slow?